# How to loop multiple exposures and outcomes as well as different models with glm in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, glm

The code below currently runs unadjusted glm for each exposure on each outcome (3 exposures per outcome) and exports the results into a list. For each exposure, I need 3 models:
**model 1**: unadjusted (which we currently have), **model 2**: adjusted for cov1, **model 3**: adjusted for cov1, cov2 and cov3

How would I implement the different models into this code?

```
amino_df <- data.frame(y = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), y2 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.3), y3 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.2), y4 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.22),
                       exp1 = rnorm(100), exp2 = rnorm(100), exp3 = rnorm(100),
                       cov1 = rnorm(100), cov2 = rnorm(100), cov3 = rnorm(100))

exp <- c("exp1", "exp2", "exp3")
y <- c("y", "y2","y3","y4")
cov <- c("cov1", "cov2", "cov3")

obs_results <- replicate(length(y), data.frame())  

for(j in seq_along(y)){
  for (i in seq_along(exp)){
    mod <- as.formula(paste(y[j], "~", exp[i]))
    glmmodel <- glm(formula = mod, family = binomial, data = amino_df)
    
    obs_results[[j]][i,1] <- names(coef(glmmodel))[2]
    obs_results[[j]][i,2] <- exp(glmmodel$coefficients[2])
    obs_results[[j]][i,3] <- summary(glmmodel)$coefficients[2,2]
    obs_results[[j]][i,4] <- summary(glmmodel)$coefficients[2,4]
    obs_results[[j]][i,5] <- exp(confint.default(glmmodel)[2,1])
    obs_results[[j]][i,6] <- exp(confint.default(glmmodel)[2,2])
  }
  colnames(obs_results[[j]]) <- c("exposure","OR", "SE", "P_value", "95_CI_LOW","95_CI_HIGH")
}
names(obs_results) <- y

obs_df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(obs_results, as.data.frame))
```

EDIT - I now have a solution:

Further question, could this code below be adapted to include different models for the different exposures? So for exp1, adjust for all 3 cons: cov1, cov2, cov3, but for exp2 adjust for cov1, cov2 only? and exp3 cov2 and cov1 only?

```
amino_df <- data.frame(y = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), y2 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.3), 
                       y3 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.2), y4 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.22),
                       exp1 = rnorm(100), exp2 = rnorm(100), exp3 = rnorm(100),
                       cov1 = rnorm(100), cov2 = rnorm(100), cov3 = rnorm(100))

exp <- c("exp1", "exp2", "exp3")
y <- c("y", "y2","y3","y4")
model <- c("", "+ cov1", "+ cov1 + cov2 + cov3")

obs_df <- lapply(y, function(j){
    lapply(exp, function(i){
        lapply(model, function(h){
            mod = as.formula(paste(j, "~", i, h))
            glmmodel = glm(formula = mod, family = binomial, data = amino_df)
            
            obs_results = data.frame(
                outcome = j,
                exposure = names(coef(glmmodel))[2], 
                covariate = h,
                OR = exp(glmmodel$coefficients[2]), 
                SE = summary(glmmodel)$coefficients[2,2], 
                P_value = summary(glmmodel)$coefficients[2,4], 
                `95_CI_LOW` = exp(confint.default(glmmodel)[2,1]), 
                `95_CI_HIGH` = exp(confint.default(glmmodel)[2,2])
            )
            return(obs_results)
        }) %>% bind_rows
    }) %>% bind_rows
}) %>% bind_rows %>% `colnames<-`(gsub("X95","95",colnames(.))) %>% `rownames<-`(NULL)

head(obs_df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like how you specified `exp` and `y` at the beginning, you can specify the different model types.

Here is an approach using lapply() instead of for-loops:

```r
amino_df <- data.frame(y = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), y2 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.3), 
                       y3 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.2), y4 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.22),
                       exp1 = rnorm(100), exp2 = rnorm(100), exp3 = rnorm(100),
                       cov1 = rnorm(100), cov2 = rnorm(100), cov3 = rnorm(100))

exp <- c("exp1", "exp2", "exp3")
y <- c("y", "y2","y3","y4")
model <- c("", "+ cov1", "+ cov1 + cov2 + cov3")

obs_df <- lapply(y, function(j){
    lapply(exp, function(i){
        lapply(model, function(h){
            mod = as.formula(paste(j, "~", i, h))
            glmmodel = glm(formula = mod, family = binomial, data = amino_df)
            
            obs_results = data.frame(
                outcome = j,
                exposure = names(coef(glmmodel))[2], 
                covariate = h,
                OR = exp(glmmodel$coefficients[2]), 
                SE = summary(glmmodel)$coefficients[2,2], 
                P_value = summary(glmmodel)$coefficients[2,4], 
                `95_CI_LOW` = exp(confint.default(glmmodel)[2,1]), 
                `95_CI_HIGH` = exp(confint.default(glmmodel)[2,2])
            )
            return(obs_results)
        }) %>% bind_rows
    }) %>% bind_rows
}) %>% bind_rows %>% `colnames<-`(gsub("X95","95",colnames(.))) %>% `rownames<-`(NULL)

head(obs_df)
#  outcome exposure            covariate        OR        SE   P_value 95_CI_LOW 95_CI_HIGH
#1       y     exp1                      0.9425290 0.2125285 0.7806305 0.6214270   1.429550
#2       y     exp1               + cov1 0.9356460 0.2138513 0.7557639 0.6152917   1.422794
#3       y     exp1 + cov1 + cov2 + cov3 0.9638427 0.2174432 0.8655098 0.6293876   1.476027
#4       y     exp2                      1.3297429 0.1865916 0.1266809 0.9224452   1.916879
#5       y     exp2               + cov1 1.3300740 0.1866225 0.1264124 0.9226190   1.917473
#6       y     exp2 + cov1 + cov2 + cov3 1.3558196 0.1903111 0.1097054 0.9337031   1.968770
```

I included `gsub("X95","95",colnames(.))` at the end because when creating new data frames, column names that begin with a number (i.e., "95_CI_LOW", "95_CI_HIGH") get an "X" inserted at the beginning by default; this code removes it.

**Supplement**

If different exposures are uniquely adjusted with different covariates in your models, the following can be done instead. The easiest solution is to run all possible exposure+covariate combinations through the code above, and then filter `obs_df` (with `filter()`) to select only the analyses that you want. However, it means it will take unnecessarily longer to run if you are working with large datasets.

A more direct approach is to enter specifically which exposure+covariate combinations to include in the `model` and remove the `lapply(exp)` function (and edit the core function accordingly):

```r
model <- c("exp1 + cov1 + cov2 + cov3", "exp2 + cov1 + cov2", "exp3 + cov1")

obs_df <- lapply(y, function(j){
    lapply(model, function(h){
        mod = as.formula(paste(j, "~", h))
        glmmodel = glm(formula = mod, family = binomial, data = amino_df)
            
        obs_results = data.frame(
            outcome = j,
            exposure = names(coef(glmmodel))[2], 
            covariate = gsub(names(coef(glmmodel))[2],"",h), # gsub to remove exposure from covariate(s)
            OR = exp(glmmodel$coefficients[2]), 
            SE = summary(glmmodel)$coefficients[2,2], 
            P_value = summary(glmmodel)$coefficients[2,4], 
            `95_CI_LOW` = exp(confint.default(glmmodel)[2,1]), 
            `95_CI_HIGH` = exp(confint.default(glmmodel)[2,2])
        )
        return(obs_results)
    }) %>% bind_rows
}) %>% bind_rows %>% `colnames<-`(gsub("X95","95",colnames(.))) %>% `rownames<-`(NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks! Would there be a way to adjust for different models for the different exposures? so for exp1, adjust for cov1, cov2, cov3, but for exp2 adjust for cov1, cov2 only?

Comment: There are ways. Option 1) Run every possible exposure+covariate combination (like the code above) and then use `filter()` to select the ones you want--this would be the easiest modification to the code but will take unnecessarily longer to run unneeded analyses. Option 2) Change `model` to include only the exposure+covariate combinations that you want, and then remove the `lapply(exp, ...)` loop and the "i" from the `mod` formula.

Comment: @KurtTaylor, I updated the answer with a supplement to answer your follow-up question

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Works great on the simulated dataset. Any idea why I am getting this when working with my real dataset whereby CHD_any is my only outcome? ```Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: CHD_any ~```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen that error before. Possible things to check: is CHD_any a numeric or factor class? Are your other variables a numeric/integer or factor/character class? Are there any typos? If you were to run a single `glm()` model with your variables, do you still get the error?

Comment: That's an error that comes from the formula parsing for a model with no covariates.

Comment: You may be missing independent variables on the right side of the tilde. You may have excluded the exposure variable from the formula as well. I get a similar error when I try that.

Comment: Mikko - great spot. I hadn't added the exposure into the empty " " which was from the first part of the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend collecting the different components that you wish to vary
between models into a data frame, and building that accordingly:

```r
library(tidyverse)

y <- c("y", "y2","y3","y4")
exp <- c("exp1", "exp2", "exp3")
cov <- list(character(), "cov1", c("cov1", "cov2", "cov3"))

# each covariate for each exposure
models1 <- crossing(outcome = y, exposure = exp, covariates = cov)
models1
#> # A tibble: 36 x 3
#>    outcome exposure covariates
#>    <chr>   <chr>    <list>    
#>  1 y       exp1     <chr [0]> 
#>  2 y       exp1     <chr [1]> 
#>  3 y       exp1     <chr [3]> 
#>  4 y       exp2     <chr [0]> 
#>  5 y       exp2     <chr [1]> 
#>  6 y       exp2     <chr [3]> 
#>  7 y       exp3     <chr [0]> 
#>  8 y       exp3     <chr [1]> 
#>  9 y       exp3     <chr [3]> 
#> 10 y2      exp1     <chr [0]> 
#> # ... with 26 more rows

# covariates specific per exposure
models2 <- crossing(outcome = y, nesting(exposure = exp, covariates = cov))
models2
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    outcome exposure covariates
#>    <chr>   <chr>    <list>    
#>  1 y       exp1     <chr [0]> 
#>  2 y       exp2     <chr [1]> 
#>  3 y       exp3     <chr [3]> 
#>  4 y2      exp1     <chr [0]> 
#>  5 y2      exp2     <chr [1]> 
#>  6 y2      exp3     <chr [3]> 
#>  7 y3      exp1     <chr [0]> 
#>  8 y3      exp2     <chr [1]> 
#>  9 y3      exp3     <chr [3]> 
#> 10 y4      exp1     <chr [0]> 
#> 11 y4      exp2     <chr [1]> 
#> 12 y4      exp3     <chr [3]>
```

Then put your model fitting and summary into a function that operates on
those components:

```r
fit_model <- function(outcome, exposure, covariates) {
  formula = reformulate(c(exposure, covariates), outcome)
  glmmodel = glm(formula = formula, family = binomial, data = amino_df)
  
  # using data.frame would not handle the covariate list column properly
  obs_results = tibble(
    outcome = outcome,
    exposure = names(coef(glmmodel))[2], 
    covariate = list(covariates),
    OR = exp(glmmodel$coefficients[2]), 
    SE = summary(glmmodel)$coefficients[2,2], 
    P_value = summary(glmmodel)$coefficients[2,4], 
    `95_CI_LOW` = exp(confint.default(glmmodel)[2,1]), 
    `95_CI_HIGH` = exp(confint.default(glmmodel)[2,2])
  )
  
  return(obs_results)
}
```

With those in place, you can use `pmap()` to fit the model for each row
in your specification data frame:

```r
amino_df <- data.frame(y = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), y2 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.3), 
                       y3 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.2), y4 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.22),
                       exp1 = rnorm(100), exp2 = rnorm(100), exp3 = rnorm(100),
                       cov1 = rnorm(100), cov2 = rnorm(100), cov3 = rnorm(100))

# each covariate for each exposure
pmap_df(models1, fit_model)
#> # A tibble: 36 x 8
#>    outcome exposure covariate    OR    SE P_value `95_CI_LOW` `95_CI_HIGH`
#>    <chr>   <chr>    <list>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
#>  1 y       exp1     <chr [0]> 1.01  0.191  0.944        0.697         1.47
#>  2 y       exp1     <chr [1]> 1.01  0.191  0.947        0.697         1.47
#>  3 y       exp1     <chr [3]> 0.990 0.194  0.960        0.677         1.45
#>  4 y       exp2     <chr [0]> 1.26  0.215  0.281        0.827         1.92
#>  5 y       exp2     <chr [1]> 1.29  0.220  0.244        0.840         1.99
#>  6 y       exp2     <chr [3]> 1.31  0.222  0.229        0.845         2.02
#>  7 y       exp3     <chr [0]> 1.43  0.216  0.0969       0.937         2.19
#>  8 y       exp3     <chr [1]> 1.43  0.217  0.101        0.933         2.18
#>  9 y       exp3     <chr [3]> 1.36  0.221  0.166        0.881         2.09
#> 10 y2      exp1     <chr [0]> 1.55  0.230  0.0580       0.985         2.43
#> # ... with 26 more rows

# covariates specific per exposure
pmap_df(models2, fit_model)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 8
#>    outcome exposure covariate    OR    SE P_value `95_CI_LOW` `95_CI_HIGH`
#>    <chr>   <chr>    <list>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
#>  1 y       exp1     <chr [0]> 1.01  0.191  0.944        0.697         1.47
#>  2 y       exp2     <chr [1]> 1.29  0.220  0.244        0.840         1.99
#>  3 y       exp3     <chr [3]> 1.36  0.221  0.166        0.881         2.09
#>  4 y2      exp1     <chr [0]> 1.55  0.230  0.0580       0.985         2.43
#>  5 y2      exp2     <chr [1]> 0.717 0.249  0.182        0.441         1.17
#>  6 y2      exp3     <chr [3]> 0.999 0.241  0.996        0.622         1.60
#>  7 y3      exp1     <chr [0]> 1.21  0.243  0.442        0.749         1.94
#>  8 y3      exp2     <chr [1]> 0.822 0.267  0.463        0.487         1.39
#>  9 y3      exp3     <chr [3]> 1.56  0.269  0.0980       0.921         2.64
#> 10 y4      exp1     <chr [0]> 1.12  0.224  0.601        0.725         1.74
#> 11 y4      exp2     <chr [1]> 0.721 0.255  0.200        0.437         1.19
#> 12 y4      exp3     <chr [3]> 0.767 0.252  0.291        0.468         1.26
```