# lm() looped over factor variable while dropping single-level factor variables from the model

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I'm trying to loop over a factor variable (`location`) and building a separate model for each level of that factor. Depending on the `location`, however, there are  single-level factor variables, which is giving me this error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
Called from: `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]])
```

So depending on the `location`, I want to drop any single-level factors from the model. I've tried splitting the data into one dataset that doesn't have any single-level factors and another that does, but I don't know how to drop a given factor variable depending on the location.

This will give you the error:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(df, key = "location")
lapply(unique(dt$location), function(z) lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5, data = dt[J(z),]))
```

I'm not very comfortable with data.table, however, so any non-data.table solution would be really helpful. Thank you.

Some data:

```
y <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 50, 5) 
x1 <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 3)                                         
location <- factor(c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20), rep(4, 20), rep(5, 20)))
x2 <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 25, sd = 3)
x3 <- factor(sample(c(0, 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE))
x4 <- factor(ifelse(location == 1, 0, 
                ifelse(location == 2, sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = TRUE), 
                       ifelse(location == 3, 1, 
                              ifelse(location == 4, 0, sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = TRUE))))))
x5 <- factor(ifelse(location == 1, sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = TRUE),
                     ifelse(location == 2, 1, 
                            ifelse(location == 3, sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = TRUE),  
                                   ifelse(location == 4, sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = TRUE), 0)))))

df <- data.frame(y, location, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
```

Comment: I tried running your `lm(...)` formula for each of the location levels. I think you are getting the "contrasts" error because some of your `x4` and `x5` factors do not have two or more levels at each location. For example, it works if I run `lapply(unique(df$location), function(z) lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df[df$location==z,]))` but not if I run `lapply(unique(df$location), function(z) lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = df[df$location==z,]))`, where the latter includes `+ x4`.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I created the sample data to do that. Sorry if my post wasn’t clear. I’m getting the contrast error because some of the factor variables don’t have two or more levels depending on the location. For each location that has a single-level factor variable, I want to drop that factor variable from the model for that location.

Comment: Oh, I think I may have misread. I previously posted a solution to another thread that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64801181/6288065. There may be parts of it that you may not need for your solution here, but I think the gist of how you can run `lapply()` through different models is there. Let me know if it's not clear. I can re-work a solution for you here.

Comment: Thank you. I’ve been trying to use lapply() but the real dataset has more than two factor variables that are “problematic” so I’ve been struggling to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model's formula is conditional on whether or not there are enough levels in each independent variable to be included.

You can create a formula based on these conditions (e.g., using `ifelse()`) and then feed the formula to the model inside `lapply()`.

Here is a solution:

```r
lapply(unique(df$location), function(z) {
    sub_df = dplyr::filter(df, location == z) # subset by location
    form_x4 = ifelse(length(unique(sub_df$x4)) > 1, "+ x4", "")
    form_x5 = ifelse(length(unique(sub_df$x5)) > 1, "+ x5", "")
    form = as.formula(paste("y ~ x1 + x2 + x3", form_x4, form_x5))
    return(lm(data = sub_df, formula = form))
})
```

The `form` inside the above `lapply(...)` combines the consistent part of the `lm()` formula with multiple variables that meet the conditions to be used in the formula. If a variable only has a single level, the `ifelse()` statement allows you to treat it as if it's not there when putting it in the formula.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use it on the actual data. Is there a way to know which model corresponds to which location from the model summary?

Comment: The simplest way to show the location from each model is to include `print(z)` inside the `lapply(...)`. Otherwise, if you want something easier to work with, you may want to create a custom summary table/data frame of the models, like the one shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64801181/6288065. You can add the location as a column in the table.